# "Story" proof for $\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}=(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3\cdot1$

Tags: combinatorics

I intuitively understand how this works if the story is that you're counting each way to pair each member of a group of size $(2n)!$. But, I am having trouble walking through the computation and the rationale for each step, especially for the $2^n$ term.

**Example: $n=2$**

For example, if the group consisted of $4$ people, $n=2$, and the solution is $3$. This makes sense from the following, step-wise calculations:

1. Counting the permutations of groups of size $n$ taken from $2n$ is $\frac{(2n!)}{n!}=\frac{(2\cdot2)!)}{2!}=12$.
2. We divide this by $2^1$ because we "assign" half of the permutations to the other half. Think: each "team" is a permutation, and we need each "team" to play another "team" (i.e., a permutation that does not have the same elements of the former permutation which it is being paired with). (E.g., AB "paired up" with CD). These pairings are called "games". Therefore, $\frac{12}{2}=6$.
3. So, now we see that we have counted all the "games" and we have to get rid of duplicate "games." We divide by $2^1$ again because each way to pair constituent members of a "game" is counted twice. If you're keeping score at home, we've explained the $2^n$ term for this example. See below for the duplicates:

> AB CD is the same as BA DC.
>   
>  BC AD is the same as CB DA.
>   
> BD CA is the same as DB AC.

We've arrived at the answer: $3=(2(2)-1)(2(2)-3)=3\cdot1$. So far, so good. Let's try another easy example.

**Example: $n=3$** ... AKA where I get stuck.

1. Same as above.
2. All good here. I've got it down to $\frac{((2\cdot3)!)}{2^1\cdot3!}=60$. I know the answer is $15$.
3. This is where the wheels come off for me. I've got the "games", but I have no idea why we are dividing by $2^2$. It has occurred to me that the second time I divided by $2$ in the example above (where $n=2$), it was $2!=2^1$ which eliminates all duplicate "games". This time, therefore, I keep wanting to divide by $6!$ to eliminate duplicate "games," but I know this is wrong and not the "story," per se (i.e., the "story" being how many ways to pair people in a group of $(2n)!$)

Hopefully, this makes sense and someone might be able to shed some light on why there is redundancy in counting of games (i.e., each unique "game" is counted $2^2=4$ times). How would I show this was some of the "games" being made explicit/manual counting (as I did in the example above)?

Thanks, all, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $(2n)!$ ways to line up the $2n$ people in two facing rows of $n$. For example, if $n=3$ and the people are $1,2,3,4,5$, and $6$, and we start with the permutation $253461$, we can line them up like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&5&3\\
4&6&1
\end{array}\tag{1}$$

Here $2$ and $4$ face each other, $5$ and $6$ face each other, and $3$ and $1$ face each other.

This produces $n$ facing pairs; in my little example the pairs are $\{2,4\},\{5,6\}$, and $\{1,3\}$. However, there are many other ways to produce the same set of pairs. First, we can permute the $n$ columns (pairs) in any of $n!$ different orders. In my example that gives us the following $3!=6$ different arrangements:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&5&3\\
4&6&1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&3&5\\
4&1&6
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
5&2&3\\
6&4&1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
5&3&2\\
6&1&4
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
3&2&5\\
1&4&6
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
3&5&2\\
1&6&4
\end{array}$$

These correspond to the $6$ permutations $253461$, $235416$, $523641$, $325146$, and $352164$.

Thus, there are at least $n!$ different permutations of the $2n$ people that lead to the same $n$ pairs. But in fact there are more: in each column we can interchange the top and bottom members of the pair. The original arrangement $(1)$ leads in this way to $2^3$ possible arrangements, since we can switch top and bottom of any of the $2^3$ possible sets of pairs. These arrangements are:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&5&3\\
4&6&1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
4&5&3\\
2&6&1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&6&3\\
4&5&1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&5&1\\
4&6&3
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
4&6&3\\
2&5&1
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
4&5&1\\
2&6&3
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2&6&1\\
4&5&3
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
4&6&1\\
2&5&3
\end{array}$$

They correspond to the permutations $253461$, $453261$, $263451$, and so on.

Thus, each possible division of the $2n$ people into $n$ pairs arises from $2^nn!$ different permutations of the $2n$ people: each permutation yields a lineup like $(1)$, and we can then permute the columns in any of $n!$ different ways and switch some top and bottom elements in $2^n$ different ways to get $2^nn!$ different lineups. These $2^nn!$ lineups are the only ones that yield this particular pairing of the $2n$ people, so the $(2n)!$ permutations count each pairing exactly $2^nn!$ times, and there are

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$

possible pairings.

To get the righthand side, number the $2n$ people $1$ through $2n$. There are $2n-1$ ways to choose a partner for $1$. Now eliminate $1$ and $1$’s partner; there are $2n-2$ people left, so there are $2n-3$ ways to pick a partner for the person with the smallest remaining number. Now eliminate this pair to leave $2n-4$ people; there are $2n-5$ ways to pick a partner for the person with the smallest remaining number. Continue in this fashion to see that there are

$$(2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots(3)(1)$$

ways to pair up the $2n$ people.

Comment: Wow, this was immensely helpful. Thanks, Brian!

Comment: @Per48edjes: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We divide by $n!$ because the order of the $n$ groups is irrelevant. We divide by $2^n$ because for each of the $n$ pairs, the order of the people in the pair is also irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a set with $2n$ elements, so that $(2n)!$ is the number of permutations of $S$.

Dividing by $2^n$ produces $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$, the number of ordered partitions of $S$ into $n$ pairs.

Then dividing by $n!$ produces $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$, the number of unordered partitions of $S$ into $n$ pairs.

---

For $n=3$, let $S=\{\textsf{A,B,C,D,E,F}\}$. Then the $720$ permutations of $S$ are

```
(A, B, C, D, E, F)
(A, B, C, D, F, E)
(A, B, C, E, D, F)
(A, B, C, E, F, D)
(A, B, C, F, D, E)
(A, B, C, F, E, D)
(A, B, D, C, E, F)
(A, B, D, C, F, E)
(A, B, D, E, C, F)
(A, B, D, E, F, C)
(A, B, D, F, C, E)
(A, B, D, F, E, C)
(A, B, E, C, D, F)
(A, B, E, C, F, D)
(A, B, E, D, C, F)
(A, B, E, D, F, C)
(A, B, E, F, C, D)
(A, B, E, F, D, C)
(A, B, F, C, D, E)
(A, B, F, C, E, D)
(A, B, F, D, C, E)
(A, B, F, D, E, C)
(A, B, F, E, C, D)
(A, B, F, E, D, C)
(A, C, B, D, E, F)
(A, C, B, D, F, E)
(A, C, B, E, D, F)
(A, C, B, E, F, D)
(A, C, B, F, D, E)
(A, C, B, F, E, D)
(A, C, D, B, E, F)
(A, C, D, B, F, E)
(A, C, D, E, B, F)
(A, C, D, E, F, B)
(A, C, D, F, B, E)
(A, C, D, F, E, B)
(A, C, E, B, D, F)
(A, C, E, B, F, D)
(A, C, E, D, B, F)
(A, C, E, D, F, B)
(A, C, E, F, B, D)
(A, C, E, F, D, B)
(A, C, F, B, D, E)
(A, C, F, B, E, D)
(A, C, F, D, B, E)
(A, C, F, D, E, B)
(A, C, F, E, B, D)
(A, C, F, E, D, B)
(A, D, B, C, E, F)
(A, D, B, C, F, E)
(A, D, B, E, C, F)
(A, D, B, E, F, C)
(A, D, B, F, C, E)
(A, D, B, F, E, C)
(A, D, C, B, E, F)
(A, D, C, B, F, E)
(A, D, C, E, B, F)
(A, D, C, E, F, B)
(A, D, C, F, B, E)
(A, D, C, F, E, B)
(A, D, E, B, C, F)
(A, D, E, B, F, C)
(A, D, E, C, B, F)
(A, D, E, C, F, B)
(A, D, E, F, B, C)
(A, D, E, F, C, B)
(A, D, F, B, C, E)
(A, D, F, B, E, C)
(A, D, F, C, B, E)
(A, D, F, C, E, B)
(A, D, F, E, B, C)
(A, D, F, E, C, B)
(A, E, B, C, D, F)
(A, E, B, C, F, D)
(A, E, B, D, C, F)
(A, E, B, D, F, C)
(A, E, B, F, C, D)
(A, E, B, F, D, C)
(A, E, C, B, D, F)
(A, E, C, B, F, D)
(A, E, C, D, B, F)
(A, E, C, D, F, B)
(A, E, C, F, B, D)
(A, E, C, F, D, B)
(A, E, D, B, C, F)
(A, E, D, B, F, C)
(A, E, D, C, B, F)
(A, E, D, C, F, B)
(A, E, D, F, B, C)
(A, E, D, F, C, B)
(A, E, F, B, C, D)
(A, E, F, B, D, C)
(A, E, F, C, B, D)
(A, E, F, C, D, B)
(A, E, F, D, B, C)
(A, E, F, D, C, B)
(A, F, B, C, D, E)
(A, F, B, C, E, D)
(A, F, B, D, C, E)
(A, F, B, D, E, C)
(A, F, B, E, C, D)
(A, F, B, E, D, C)
(A, F, C, B, D, E)
(A, F, C, B, E, D)
(A, F, C, D, B, E)
(A, F, C, D, E, B)
(A, F, C, E, B, D)
(A, F, C, E, D, B)
(A, F, D, B, C, E)
(A, F, D, B, E, C)
(A, F, D, C, B, E)
(A, F, D, C, E, B)
(A, F, D, E, B, C)
(A, F, D, E, C, B)
(A, F, E, B, C, D)
(A, F, E, B, D, C)
(A, F, E, C, B, D)
(A, F, E, C, D, B)
(A, F, E, D, B, C)
(A, F, E, D, C, B)
(B, A, C, D, E, F)
(B, A, C, D, F, E)
(B, A, C, E, D, F)
(B, A, C, E, F, D)
(B, A, C, F, D, E)
(B, A, C, F, E, D)
(B, A, D, C, E, F)
(B, A, D, C, F, E)
(B, A, D, E, C, F)
(B, A, D, E, F, C)
(B, A, D, F, C, E)
(B, A, D, F, E, C)
(B, A, E, C, D, F)
(B, A, E, C, F, D)
(B, A, E, D, C, F)
(B, A, E, D, F, C)
(B, A, E, F, C, D)
(B, A, E, F, D, C)
(B, A, F, C, D, E)
(B, A, F, C, E, D)
(B, A, F, D, C, E)
(B, A, F, D, E, C)
(B, A, F, E, C, D)
(B, A, F, E, D, C)
(B, C, A, D, E, F)
(B, C, A, D, F, E)
(B, C, A, E, D, F)
(B, C, A, E, F, D)
(B, C, A, F, D, E)
(B, C, A, F, E, D)
(B, C, D, A, E, F)
(B, C, D, A, F, E)
(B, C, D, E, A, F)
(B, C, D, E, F, A)
(B, C, D, F, A, E)
(B, C, D, F, E, A)
(B, C, E, A, D, F)
(B, C, E, A, F, D)
(B, C, E, D, A, F)
(B, C, E, D, F, A)
(B, C, E, F, A, D)
(B, C, E, F, D, A)
(B, C, F, A, D, E)
(B, C, F, A, E, D)
(B, C, F, D, A, E)
(B, C, F, D, E, A)
(B, C, F, E, A, D)
(B, C, F, E, D, A)
(B, D, A, C, E, F)
(B, D, A, C, F, E)
(B, D, A, E, C, F)
(B, D, A, E, F, C)
(B, D, A, F, C, E)
(B, D, A, F, E, C)
(B, D, C, A, E, F)
(B, D, C, A, F, E)
(B, D, C, E, A, F)
(B, D, C, E, F, A)
(B, D, C, F, A, E)
(B, D, C, F, E, A)
(B, D, E, A, C, F)
(B, D, E, A, F, C)
(B, D, E, C, A, F)
(B, D, E, C, F, A)
(B, D, E, F, A, C)
(B, D, E, F, C, A)
(B, D, F, A, C, E)
(B, D, F, A, E, C)
(B, D, F, C, A, E)
(B, D, F, C, E, A)
(B, D, F, E, A, C)
(B, D, F, E, C, A)
(B, E, A, C, D, F)
(B, E, A, C, F, D)
(B, E, A, D, C, F)
(B, E, A, D, F, C)
(B, E, A, F, C, D)
(B, E, A, F, D, C)
(B, E, C, A, D, F)
(B, E, C, A, F, D)
(B, E, C, D, A, F)
(B, E, C, D, F, A)
(B, E, C, F, A, D)
(B, E, C, F, D, A)
(B, E, D, A, C, F)
(B, E, D, A, F, C)
(B, E, D, C, A, F)
(B, E, D, C, F, A)
(B, E, D, F, A, C)
(B, E, D, F, C, A)
(B, E, F, A, C, D)
(B, E, F, A, D, C)
(B, E, F, C, A, D)
(B, E, F, C, D, A)
(B, E, F, D, A, C)
(B, E, F, D, C, A)
(B, F, A, C, D, E)
(B, F, A, C, E, D)
(B, F, A, D, C, E)
(B, F, A, D, E, C)
(B, F, A, E, C, D)
(B, F, A, E, D, C)
(B, F, C, A, D, E)
(B, F, C, A, E, D)
(B, F, C, D, A, E)
(B, F, C, D, E, A)
(B, F, C, E, A, D)
(B, F, C, E, D, A)
(B, F, D, A, C, E)
(B, F, D, A, E, C)
(B, F, D, C, A, E)
(B, F, D, C, E, A)
(B, F, D, E, A, C)
(B, F, D, E, C, A)
(B, F, E, A, C, D)
(B, F, E, A, D, C)
(B, F, E, C, A, D)
(B, F, E, C, D, A)
(B, F, E, D, A, C)
(B, F, E, D, C, A)
(C, A, B, D, E, F)
(C, A, B, D, F, E)
(C, A, B, E, D, F)
(C, A, B, E, F, D)
(C, A, B, F, D, E)
(C, A, B, F, E, D)
(C, A, D, B, E, F)
(C, A, D, B, F, E)
(C, A, D, E, B, F)
(C, A, D, E, F, B)
(C, A, D, F, B, E)
(C, A, D, F, E, B)
(C, A, E, B, D, F)
(C, A, E, B, F, D)
(C, A, E, D, B, F)
(C, A, E, D, F, B)
(C, A, E, F, B, D)
(C, A, E, F, D, B)
(C, A, F, B, D, E)
(C, A, F, B, E, D)
(C, A, F, D, B, E)
(C, A, F, D, E, B)
(C, A, F, E, B, D)
(C, A, F, E, D, B)
(C, B, A, D, E, F)
(C, B, A, D, F, E)
(C, B, A, E, D, F)
(C, B, A, E, F, D)
(C, B, A, F, D, E)
(C, B, A, F, E, D)
(C, B, D, A, E, F)
(C, B, D, A, F, E)
(C, B, D, E, A, F)
(C, B, D, E, F, A)
(C, B, D, F, A, E)
(C, B, D, F, E, A)
(C, B, E, A, D, F)
(C, B, E, A, F, D)
(C, B, E, D, A, F)
(C, B, E, D, F, A)
(C, B, E, F, A, D)
(C, B, E, F, D, A)
(C, B, F, A, D, E)
(C, B, F, A, E, D)
(C, B, F, D, A, E)
(C, B, F, D, E, A)
(C, B, F, E, A, D)
(C, B, F, E, D, A)
(C, D, A, B, E, F)
(C, D, A, B, F, E)
(C, D, A, E, B, F)
(C, D, A, E, F, B)
(C, D, A, F, B, E)
(C, D, A, F, E, B)
(C, D, B, A, E, F)
(C, D, B, A, F, E)
(C, D, B, E, A, F)
(C, D, B, E, F, A)
(C, D, B, F, A, E)
(C, D, B, F, E, A)
(C, D, E, A, B, F)
(C, D, E, A, F, B)
(C, D, E, B, A, F)
(C, D, E, B, F, A)
(C, D, E, F, A, B)
(C, D, E, F, B, A)
(C, D, F, A, B, E)
(C, D, F, A, E, B)
(C, D, F, B, A, E)
(C, D, F, B, E, A)
(C, D, F, E, A, B)
(C, D, F, E, B, A)
(C, E, A, B, D, F)
(C, E, A, B, F, D)
(C, E, A, D, B, F)
(C, E, A, D, F, B)
(C, E, A, F, B, D)
(C, E, A, F, D, B)
(C, E, B, A, D, F)
(C, E, B, A, F, D)
(C, E, B, D, A, F)
(C, E, B, D, F, A)
(C, E, B, F, A, D)
(C, E, B, F, D, A)
(C, E, D, A, B, F)
(C, E, D, A, F, B)
(C, E, D, B, A, F)
(C, E, D, B, F, A)
(C, E, D, F, A, B)
(C, E, D, F, B, A)
(C, E, F, A, B, D)
(C, E, F, A, D, B)
(C, E, F, B, A, D)
(C, E, F, B, D, A)
(C, E, F, D, A, B)
(C, E, F, D, B, A)
(C, F, A, B, D, E)
(C, F, A, B, E, D)
(C, F, A, D, B, E)
(C, F, A, D, E, B)
(C, F, A, E, B, D)
(C, F, A, E, D, B)
(C, F, B, A, D, E)
(C, F, B, A, E, D)
(C, F, B, D, A, E)
(C, F, B, D, E, A)
(C, F, B, E, A, D)
(C, F, B, E, D, A)
(C, F, D, A, B, E)
(C, F, D, A, E, B)
(C, F, D, B, A, E)
(C, F, D, B, E, A)
(C, F, D, E, A, B)
(C, F, D, E, B, A)
(C, F, E, A, B, D)
(C, F, E, A, D, B)
(C, F, E, B, A, D)
(C, F, E, B, D, A)
(C, F, E, D, A, B)
(C, F, E, D, B, A)
(D, A, B, C, E, F)
(D, A, B, C, F, E)
(D, A, B, E, C, F)
(D, A, B, E, F, C)
(D, A, B, F, C, E)
(D, A, B, F, E, C)
(D, A, C, B, E, F)
(D, A, C, B, F, E)
(D, A, C, E, B, F)
(D, A, C, E, F, B)
(D, A, C, F, B, E)
(D, A, C, F, E, B)
(D, A, E, B, C, F)
(D, A, E, B, F, C)
(D, A, E, C, B, F)
(D, A, E, C, F, B)
(D, A, E, F, B, C)
(D, A, E, F, C, B)
(D, A, F, B, C, E)
(D, A, F, B, E, C)
(D, A, F, C, B, E)
(D, A, F, C, E, B)
(D, A, F, E, B, C)
(D, A, F, E, C, B)
(D, B, A, C, E, F)
(D, B, A, C, F, E)
(D, B, A, E, C, F)
(D, B, A, E, F, C)
(D, B, A, F, C, E)
(D, B, A, F, E, C)
(D, B, C, A, E, F)
(D, B, C, A, F, E)
(D, B, C, E, A, F)
(D, B, C, E, F, A)
(D, B, C, F, A, E)
(D, B, C, F, E, A)
(D, B, E, A, C, F)
(D, B, E, A, F, C)
(D, B, E, C, A, F)
(D, B, E, C, F, A)
(D, B, E, F, A, C)
(D, B, E, F, C, A)
(D, B, F, A, C, E)
(D, B, F, A, E, C)
(D, B, F, C, A, E)
(D, B, F, C, E, A)
(D, B, F, E, A, C)
(D, B, F, E, C, A)
(D, C, A, B, E, F)
(D, C, A, B, F, E)
(D, C, A, E, B, F)
(D, C, A, E, F, B)
(D, C, A, F, B, E)
(D, C, A, F, E, B)
(D, C, B, A, E, F)
(D, C, B, A, F, E)
(D, C, B, E, A, F)
(D, C, B, E, F, A)
(D, C, B, F, A, E)
(D, C, B, F, E, A)
(D, C, E, A, B, F)
(D, C, E, A, F, B)
(D, C, E, B, A, F)
(D, C, E, B, F, A)
(D, C, E, F, A, B)
(D, C, E, F, B, A)
(D, C, F, A, B, E)
(D, C, F, A, E, B)
(D, C, F, B, A, E)
(D, C, F, B, E, A)
(D, C, F, E, A, B)
(D, C, F, E, B, A)
(D, E, A, B, C, F)
(D, E, A, B, F, C)
(D, E, A, C, B, F)
(D, E, A, C, F, B)
(D, E, A, F, B, C)
(D, E, A, F, C, B)
(D, E, B, A, C, F)
(D, E, B, A, F, C)
(D, E, B, C, A, F)
(D, E, B, C, F, A)
(D, E, B, F, A, C)
(D, E, B, F, C, A)
(D, E, C, A, B, F)
(D, E, C, A, F, B)
(D, E, C, B, A, F)
(D, E, C, B, F, A)
(D, E, C, F, A, B)
(D, E, C, F, B, A)
(D, E, F, A, B, C)
(D, E, F, A, C, B)
(D, E, F, B, A, C)
(D, E, F, B, C, A)
(D, E, F, C, A, B)
(D, E, F, C, B, A)
(D, F, A, B, C, E)
(D, F, A, B, E, C)
(D, F, A, C, B, E)
(D, F, A, C, E, B)
(D, F, A, E, B, C)
(D, F, A, E, C, B)
(D, F, B, A, C, E)
(D, F, B, A, E, C)
(D, F, B, C, A, E)
(D, F, B, C, E, A)
(D, F, B, E, A, C)
(D, F, B, E, C, A)
(D, F, C, A, B, E)
(D, F, C, A, E, B)
(D, F, C, B, A, E)
(D, F, C, B, E, A)
(D, F, C, E, A, B)
(D, F, C, E, B, A)
(D, F, E, A, B, C)
(D, F, E, A, C, B)
(D, F, E, B, A, C)
(D, F, E, B, C, A)
(D, F, E, C, A, B)
(D, F, E, C, B, A)
(E, A, B, C, D, F)
(E, A, B, C, F, D)
(E, A, B, D, C, F)
(E, A, B, D, F, C)
(E, A, B, F, C, D)
(E, A, B, F, D, C)
(E, A, C, B, D, F)
(E, A, C, B, F, D)
(E, A, C, D, B, F)
(E, A, C, D, F, B)
(E, A, C, F, B, D)
(E, A, C, F, D, B)
(E, A, D, B, C, F)
(E, A, D, B, F, C)
(E, A, D, C, B, F)
(E, A, D, C, F, B)
(E, A, D, F, B, C)
(E, A, D, F, C, B)
(E, A, F, B, C, D)
(E, A, F, B, D, C)
(E, A, F, C, B, D)
(E, A, F, C, D, B)
(E, A, F, D, B, C)
(E, A, F, D, C, B)
(E, B, A, C, D, F)
(E, B, A, C, F, D)
(E, B, A, D, C, F)
(E, B, A, D, F, C)
(E, B, A, F, C, D)
(E, B, A, F, D, C)
(E, B, C, A, D, F)
(E, B, C, A, F, D)
(E, B, C, D, A, F)
(E, B, C, D, F, A)
(E, B, C, F, A, D)
(E, B, C, F, D, A)
(E, B, D, A, C, F)
(E, B, D, A, F, C)
(E, B, D, C, A, F)
(E, B, D, C, F, A)
(E, B, D, F, A, C)
(E, B, D, F, C, A)
(E, B, F, A, C, D)
(E, B, F, A, D, C)
(E, B, F, C, A, D)
(E, B, F, C, D, A)
(E, B, F, D, A, C)
(E, B, F, D, C, A)
(E, C, A, B, D, F)
(E, C, A, B, F, D)
(E, C, A, D, B, F)
(E, C, A, D, F, B)
(E, C, A, F, B, D)
(E, C, A, F, D, B)
(E, C, B, A, D, F)
(E, C, B, A, F, D)
(E, C, B, D, A, F)
(E, C, B, D, F, A)
(E, C, B, F, A, D)
(E, C, B, F, D, A)
(E, C, D, A, B, F)
(E, C, D, A, F, B)
(E, C, D, B, A, F)
(E, C, D, B, F, A)
(E, C, D, F, A, B)
(E, C, D, F, B, A)
(E, C, F, A, B, D)
(E, C, F, A, D, B)
(E, C, F, B, A, D)
(E, C, F, B, D, A)
(E, C, F, D, A, B)
(E, C, F, D, B, A)
(E, D, A, B, C, F)
(E, D, A, B, F, C)
(E, D, A, C, B, F)
(E, D, A, C, F, B)
(E, D, A, F, B, C)
(E, D, A, F, C, B)
(E, D, B, A, C, F)
(E, D, B, A, F, C)
(E, D, B, C, A, F)
(E, D, B, C, F, A)
(E, D, B, F, A, C)
(E, D, B, F, C, A)
(E, D, C, A, B, F)
(E, D, C, A, F, B)
(E, D, C, B, A, F)
(E, D, C, B, F, A)
(E, D, C, F, A, B)
(E, D, C, F, B, A)
(E, D, F, A, B, C)
(E, D, F, A, C, B)
(E, D, F, B, A, C)
(E, D, F, B, C, A)
(E, D, F, C, A, B)
(E, D, F, C, B, A)
(E, F, A, B, C, D)
(E, F, A, B, D, C)
(E, F, A, C, B, D)
(E, F, A, C, D, B)
(E, F, A, D, B, C)
(E, F, A, D, C, B)
(E, F, B, A, C, D)
(E, F, B, A, D, C)
(E, F, B, C, A, D)
(E, F, B, C, D, A)
(E, F, B, D, A, C)
(E, F, B, D, C, A)
(E, F, C, A, B, D)
(E, F, C, A, D, B)
(E, F, C, B, A, D)
(E, F, C, B, D, A)
(E, F, C, D, A, B)
(E, F, C, D, B, A)
(E, F, D, A, B, C)
(E, F, D, A, C, B)
(E, F, D, B, A, C)
(E, F, D, B, C, A)
(E, F, D, C, A, B)
(E, F, D, C, B, A)
(F, A, B, C, D, E)
(F, A, B, C, E, D)
(F, A, B, D, C, E)
(F, A, B, D, E, C)
(F, A, B, E, C, D)
(F, A, B, E, D, C)
(F, A, C, B, D, E)
(F, A, C, B, E, D)
(F, A, C, D, B, E)
(F, A, C, D, E, B)
(F, A, C, E, B, D)
(F, A, C, E, D, B)
(F, A, D, B, C, E)
(F, A, D, B, E, C)
(F, A, D, C, B, E)
(F, A, D, C, E, B)
(F, A, D, E, B, C)
(F, A, D, E, C, B)
(F, A, E, B, C, D)
(F, A, E, B, D, C)
(F, A, E, C, B, D)
(F, A, E, C, D, B)
(F, A, E, D, B, C)
(F, A, E, D, C, B)
(F, B, A, C, D, E)
(F, B, A, C, E, D)
(F, B, A, D, C, E)
(F, B, A, D, E, C)
(F, B, A, E, C, D)
(F, B, A, E, D, C)
(F, B, C, A, D, E)
(F, B, C, A, E, D)
(F, B, C, D, A, E)
(F, B, C, D, E, A)
(F, B, C, E, A, D)
(F, B, C, E, D, A)
(F, B, D, A, C, E)
(F, B, D, A, E, C)
(F, B, D, C, A, E)
(F, B, D, C, E, A)
(F, B, D, E, A, C)
(F, B, D, E, C, A)
(F, B, E, A, C, D)
(F, B, E, A, D, C)
(F, B, E, C, A, D)
(F, B, E, C, D, A)
(F, B, E, D, A, C)
(F, B, E, D, C, A)
(F, C, A, B, D, E)
(F, C, A, B, E, D)
(F, C, A, D, B, E)
(F, C, A, D, E, B)
(F, C, A, E, B, D)
(F, C, A, E, D, B)
(F, C, B, A, D, E)
(F, C, B, A, E, D)
(F, C, B, D, A, E)
(F, C, B, D, E, A)
(F, C, B, E, A, D)
(F, C, B, E, D, A)
(F, C, D, A, B, E)
(F, C, D, A, E, B)
(F, C, D, B, A, E)
(F, C, D, B, E, A)
(F, C, D, E, A, B)
(F, C, D, E, B, A)
(F, C, E, A, B, D)
(F, C, E, A, D, B)
(F, C, E, B, A, D)
(F, C, E, B, D, A)
(F, C, E, D, A, B)
(F, C, E, D, B, A)
(F, D, A, B, C, E)
(F, D, A, B, E, C)
(F, D, A, C, B, E)
(F, D, A, C, E, B)
(F, D, A, E, B, C)
(F, D, A, E, C, B)
(F, D, B, A, C, E)
(F, D, B, A, E, C)
(F, D, B, C, A, E)
(F, D, B, C, E, A)
(F, D, B, E, A, C)
(F, D, B, E, C, A)
(F, D, C, A, B, E)
(F, D, C, A, E, B)
(F, D, C, B, A, E)
(F, D, C, B, E, A)
(F, D, C, E, A, B)
(F, D, C, E, B, A)
(F, D, E, A, B, C)
(F, D, E, A, C, B)
(F, D, E, B, A, C)
(F, D, E, B, C, A)
(F, D, E, C, A, B)
(F, D, E, C, B, A)
(F, E, A, B, C, D)
(F, E, A, B, D, C)
(F, E, A, C, B, D)
(F, E, A, C, D, B)
(F, E, A, D, B, C)
(F, E, A, D, C, B)
(F, E, B, A, C, D)
(F, E, B, A, D, C)
(F, E, B, C, A, D)
(F, E, B, C, D, A)
(F, E, B, D, A, C)
(F, E, B, D, C, A)
(F, E, C, A, B, D)
(F, E, C, A, D, B)
(F, E, C, B, A, D)
(F, E, C, B, D, A)
(F, E, C, D, A, B)
(F, E, C, D, B, A)
(F, E, D, A, B, C)
(F, E, D, A, C, B)
(F, E, D, B, A, C)
(F, E, D, B, C, A)
(F, E, D, C, A, B)
(F, E, D, C, B, A)
```

The $90$ ordered partitions of $S$ into $3$ pairs are

```
({A,B}, {C,D}, {E,F})
({A,B}, {C,E}, {D,F})
({A,B}, {C,F}, {E,D})
({A,B}, {E,D}, {C,F})
({A,B}, {D,F}, {C,E})
({A,B}, {E,F}, {C,D})
({A,C}, {B,D}, {E,F})
({A,C}, {B,E}, {D,F})
({A,C}, {B,F}, {E,D})
({A,C}, {E,D}, {B,F})
({A,C}, {D,F}, {B,E})
({A,C}, {E,F}, {B,D})
({A,D}, {C,B}, {E,F})
({A,D}, {B,E}, {C,F})
({A,D}, {B,F}, {C,E})
({A,D}, {C,E}, {B,F})
({A,D}, {C,F}, {B,E})
({A,D}, {E,F}, {C,B})
({A,E}, {C,B}, {D,F})
({A,E}, {B,D}, {C,F})
({A,E}, {B,F}, {C,D})
({A,E}, {C,D}, {B,F})
({A,E}, {C,F}, {B,D})
({A,E}, {D,F}, {C,B})
({A,F}, {C,B}, {E,D})
({A,F}, {B,D}, {C,E})
({A,F}, {B,E}, {C,D})
({A,F}, {C,D}, {B,E})
({A,F}, {C,E}, {B,D})
({A,F}, {E,D}, {C,B})
({C,B}, {A,D}, {E,F})
({C,B}, {A,E}, {D,F})
({C,B}, {A,F}, {E,D})
({C,B}, {E,D}, {A,F})
({C,B}, {D,F}, {A,E})
({C,B}, {E,F}, {A,D})
({B,D}, {A,C}, {E,F})
({B,D}, {A,E}, {C,F})
({B,D}, {A,F}, {C,E})
({B,D}, {C,E}, {A,F})
({B,D}, {C,F}, {A,E})
({B,D}, {E,F}, {A,C})
({B,E}, {A,C}, {D,F})
({B,E}, {A,D}, {C,F})
({B,E}, {A,F}, {C,D})
({B,E}, {C,D}, {A,F})
({B,E}, {C,F}, {A,D})
({B,E}, {D,F}, {A,C})
({B,F}, {A,C}, {E,D})
({B,F}, {A,D}, {C,E})
({B,F}, {A,E}, {C,D})
({B,F}, {C,D}, {A,E})
({B,F}, {C,E}, {A,D})
({B,F}, {E,D}, {A,C})
({C,D}, {A,B}, {E,F})
({C,D}, {A,E}, {B,F})
({C,D}, {A,F}, {B,E})
({C,D}, {B,E}, {A,F})
({C,D}, {B,F}, {A,E})
({C,D}, {E,F}, {A,B})
({C,E}, {A,B}, {D,F})
({C,E}, {A,D}, {B,F})
({C,E}, {A,F}, {B,D})
({C,E}, {B,D}, {A,F})
({C,E}, {B,F}, {A,D})
({C,E}, {D,F}, {A,B})
({C,F}, {A,B}, {E,D})
({C,F}, {A,D}, {B,E})
({C,F}, {A,E}, {B,D})
({C,F}, {B,D}, {A,E})
({C,F}, {B,E}, {A,D})
({C,F}, {E,D}, {A,B})
({E,D}, {A,B}, {C,F})
({E,D}, {A,C}, {B,F})
({E,D}, {A,F}, {C,B})
({E,D}, {C,B}, {A,F})
({E,D}, {B,F}, {A,C})
({E,D}, {C,F}, {A,B})
({D,F}, {A,B}, {C,E})
({D,F}, {A,C}, {B,E})
({D,F}, {A,E}, {C,B})
({D,F}, {C,B}, {A,E})
({D,F}, {B,E}, {A,C})
({D,F}, {C,E}, {A,B})
({E,F}, {A,B}, {C,D})
({E,F}, {A,C}, {B,D})
({E,F}, {A,D}, {C,B})
({E,F}, {C,B}, {A,D})
({E,F}, {B,D}, {A,C})
({E,F}, {C,D}, {A,B})
```

The $15$ unordered partitions of $S$ into $3$ pairs are

```
{{A,B}, {C,D}, {E,F}}
{{A,B}, {C,E}, {D,F}}
{{A,B}, {C,F}, {E,D}}
{{A,C}, {B,D}, {E,F}}
{{A,C}, {B,E}, {D,F}}
{{A,C}, {B,F}, {E,D}}
{{A,D}, {C,B}, {E,F}}
{{A,D}, {B,E}, {C,F}}
{{A,D}, {B,F}, {C,E}}
{{A,E}, {C,B}, {D,F}}
{{A,E}, {B,D}, {C,F}}
{{A,E}, {B,F}, {C,D}}
{{A,F}, {C,B}, {E,D}}
{{A,F}, {B,D}, {C,E}}
{{A,F}, {B,E}, {C,D}}
```

Answer (score 0):

$n = 3$

We have $6$ people.
There are ${6\choose 2}$ ways to make the first paring.  That leave 4 left to pair, we pair them up.  And the last pair fall into place.

${6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2} = \frac {6!}{(2!)(2!)(2!)} = \frac {6!}{2^3}$

But this suggests that the first couple paired is distinct from the second couple paired, and we don't care about these permutations.

$\frac {6!}{2^3(3!)}$

Can you abstract from here to larger groups?

Multiply that out and you get: